# Question on point-countable base

Tags: general-topology

Could the space havig point-countable base implies it having $G_\delta$-diagonal? If it is true, I want to know that why the first countable space could not implies $G_\delta$-diagonal? What is the defference between them?

Thanks ahead:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example $2.11$ of [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-028-02/S0002-9939-1971-0275377-2/) is a LOTS $X$ with a point-countable base that does not have a $\sigma$-point-finite base. Byt Theorem $2.10$ of the same paper $X$ is not quasi-developable. By Proposition $1.6$ of [this paper](http://www.math.wm.edu/~lutzer/papers/PointCtblBases.pdf) $X$ does not have a quasi-$G_\delta$-diagonal and therefore does not have a $G_\delta$-diagonal. Thus, having a point-countable base does not imply having a $G_\delta$-diagonal.

The LOTS $\omega_1$ is first countable, but it does not have a $G_\delta$-diagonal.

Note that every space with a point-countable base is first countable, but $\omega_1$ is an easy example of a first countable space that is does not have a point-countable base: this follows immediately from the [pressing-down lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fodor%27s_lemma).